# Magento Price Not Updating

Tags: magento, configurable-product

We've recently installed Simple Configurable Products on our 1.4.2.0 Magento install but the price on the product isn't updating when the user selects an option, if you configure the product and add to cart the price show's up correct in the cart, just not on the product at the time of selection.

If anyone could help out on this that would be great.

Comment: what js error you are facing i believe there should be js error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the solution at - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/52582/

Comment: Sadly Magento moved or removed forum content.  Every time I try to access a link to their forum from search or direct links, I'm directed to the support home page.

Answer (score 1):

If the price and availability are not showing on `simple/virtual/downloadable` product page when there are no configurable/custom options.

The Solution is as follows:

Go to: `app/design/frontend/base/custom` `theme/layout/`

- Open the `catalog.xml` file
- Replace (line 279):

`<block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml">`

With:

`<block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">`

Answers and modules from Magento specialists @ [AgileWebSolutions](http://www.agilewebsolutions.co.uk/)